# C# Derefrenced Pointer requires sleep of 1 millisecond per iteration

Tags: c#, pointers, thread-sleep

I am writing a method that iterates over the pixels of an image and returns the sum of each column. The image is passed in as a pointer array which gets derefferenced and summed. The weird thing is, if I simply iterate through, the value of each summed column returns as 255000 (the maximum value it could be), however, if I add in a one millisecond sleep, the array has the correct, non-maximum values.

```
private unsafe int[] SumEachColumn(SharedImg camera, Cvb.Image.VPAEntry*  pVPAT, IntPtr pbase, int startsumposx =0, int endsumposx = 300)
{
    int[] horsum = new int[endsumposx - startsumposx];
    byte* pImageLine;
    for (int y = 0; y < Image.ImageHeight(camera); y++)
    {
        pImageLine = (byte*)(pbase.ToInt64() + pVPAT[y].YEntry.ToInt64());
        for (int x = startsumposx; x<endsumposx; x++)
        {
            horsum[x] += (byte)(255 - *(pImageLine + pVPAT[x].XEntry.ToInt64()));
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(1); //when commented horsum returns 255000 in each cell, when uncommented, returns values ranging from 1500-255000
    }
    return horsum;
}
```

I'm pretty new to programming and am completely stumped on what could be occuring here. unfortunately, this is supposed to run in real time off a camera, so pausing for a second each frame is not a possible solution.

Comment: Are you running this on one thread and have another thread that is writing to the same image data perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure it's the value you get, did you see it with a breakpoint or something ? If your image is just completely black when you look at it, it's because if you don't wait a small amount of time, the image won't refresh, and you'll see a black image

Comment: Add `GC.KeepAlive(null)` instead of the sleep. If this is a JIT bug then any uninterpreted function call will have the same effect. But since you are dealing with cameras here it's probably just a race condition.

Comment: @ Dimitri MockelynThis is definitely the value that I am getting, I found this by creating a breakpoint right before the return statement and "watching" the variable.

Comment: @usr tried raplacing 'Thread.Sleep(1);' with 'GC.KeepAlive(null);' But it still returned with 255000 for the whole array.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think that might actually be the problem, although I'm not sure why that would be fixed by adding in a sleep.

Comment: You give the other thread time to fill the image with valid data. When you start, you probably have a race condition where the code you've posted here runs before the other thread has received an image from the camera and stored it into place, and thus you see everything as white to begin with, hence the maximum sum.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So I tried to move the Sleep to before the for loop executes and set it to 1000 milliseconds. I would think if there were a race condition, waiting before-hand would have the same effect as waiting for small amounts within the loop, however this also returned the maximal value. Is this the wrong way of looking at it or must the problem lie somewhere else? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: OK, I'll keep looking, thanks anyway @LasseV.Karlsen.

Comment: If it is indeed a race condition, we need to see the code that calls the function as well. What types are camera and pVPAT ? how are they obtained? Are they being written to as well and when?